# Exchanges that support integrated addresses

Tags: exchange, integrated-address

Do any exchanges support Monero integrated addresses?

For those that do not yet support them, have they shared the reason why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poloniex is the exchange with the most Monero liquidity currently and now supports [integrated addresses](https://twitter.com/Poloniex/status/872008789586845696)

Another large exchange Kraken has supported Monero integrated addresses since XMR trading started in [January, 2017](http://blog.kraken.com/post/155126375697/kraken-launches-monero-trading).

Update: As of August, 2017 there are at least two more exchanges that support integrated addresses including [Tux as mentioned in this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1891/237) and [xmr.to](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/what-is-xmrdottwo). Based on current trends the level of support for integrated addresses is likely to increase in the future.

Comment: marking this is correct but I would like to see the answer updated to include Tux (mentioned above), xmr.to and any other new options.

Answer (score 8):

Tux exchange [added](https://twitter.com/tuxexchange/status/783689426794938368) Monero with integrated addresses:

Answer (score 4):

There are not any major exchanges that support integrated addresses yet, but that is likely to change:

Shapeshift is having its development team [look into supporting integrated addresses](https://np.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4r6cm3/is_shapeshift_using_integrated_addresses_now/d56yxf8)

There have been efforts to automate the generation of integrated addresses in order to make [implementation easier](https://np.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/47ckmz/can_someone_help_make_me_make_a_webform_with_an/)