# Question about mining to a remote online wallet

Tags: mymonero, solo-mining

I am running a full node on my Mac and I want to start mining some XMR.

What is the right way to mine directly to my MyMonero wallet?
Is it start_mining *my address* ?

Will it auto send the XMR to my wallet? Or do I manually have to send the XMR to my wallet?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the `start_mining <addr>` command will send your mined Monero directly to the address you specify.

Most people that run their own full node will mine to a local wallet, but mining to a web wallet while not necessarily recommended for privacy reasons is possible. Mining directly to an exchange is only possible if the exchange supports [integrated addresses](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/768/exchanges-that-support-integrated-addresses).

Comment: Much more difficult to mine to an exchange - you need to use an integrated address, and not all exchanges support them.

Comment: @hyc so it is possible but you recommend mining to an integrated address?

Comment: You cannot mine to an exchange without using an integrated address. Without an integrated address you need to use payment IDs for the exchange, and the miner has no way to specify those.

Comment: @hyc couldn't the miner combine the payment ID and the address to create an integrated address, or am I missing something?