# What is XMRdotTwo?

Tags: exchange, payment-integration, xmr.to

I heard something about XMRdotTwo (or maybe XMRdotTo?). Can someone explain to me what this is? I heard that you can use it to pay Bitcoin addresses with Monero.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably referring to [XMR.to](https://xmr.to), a website that allows people to make anonymous payments to a Bitcoin address with Monero.

[image: XMR.to website main page]

XMR is the trading symbol for Monero, which is why the domain is relevant.

You can learn more about BinaryFate, one of the founders of [XMR.to](https://xmr.to), in [this podcast](https://www.moneromonitor.com/episodes/2017-04-24-Episode-003.html).

The website has no registration. However, they log your IP address. For extra privacy, the service can be accessed through its onion (Tor) site `xmrto2bturnore26.onion`.

Comment: Is the name public by binaryFate's own explicit choice ?

Comment: @user36303 It is mentioned publicly in the linked podcast.

Comment: I make no secret about link between name and nickname but no need to feed google with explicit easy to find statement. I edited and removed name as unnecessary to (good btw) answer.

Answer (score 1):

[XMR.to](https://xmr.to/) started as an instant, no-signup, non-KYC Monero to Bitcoin exchange but has since grown to include some more services, including:

- XMR -> BTC exchange
- Public nodes, including Testnet/Stagenet and Tor nodes <sup>[[1]](https://community.xmr.to/nodes.html)</sup>
- An API for creating exchange orders/viewing price <sup>[[2]](https://xmrto-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_v2.html)</sup>
- Block explorer <sup>[[3]](https://community.xmr.to/explorer/mainnet/)</sup>
- Testnet/Stagenet faucet <sup>[[4]](https://community.xmr.to/faucet/testnet/)</sup>
- Network node map <sup>[[5]](https://community.xmr.to/network/)</sup>
- Aeon (Monero fork) version <sup>[[6]](https://aeon.to/)</sup>